# Referential equality of entity attached to multiple DbContexts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When receiving an entity from (so it is attached to) `DbContext dbContext1`, and then manually attaching this entity to `DbContext dbContext2`, will every entity (representing the same database object) received from either of these two contexts (e.g. as a query result) in the future have referential equality with the first-mentioned object?

I know that entities of the same database object always have referential equality withing the scope of one single `DbContext`, but can this be extended when attaching an entity to multiple `DbContext`s?

**Background**: I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application which does not only use the `DbContext`s coming with each per-request scope, but there is also a long-living scope for background tasks with its own `DbContext`. I want to know if entities originating within the request scope can be attached to the long-living scope so that changes to these entities within requests are also seen by the background tasks without the need to refresh those entities separately.

Comment: Not documented, but yes, if you attach it successfully, the instance will be returned by any **tracking** query for the record with the same PK . But note that doing so may cause you multithread issues.

Comment: a long-lived dbcontext is almost always a terrible idea...

Comment: @MarcGravell I see your point and I am about to refactor the background tasks so that each one has its own short-living scope. I just wanted to bring up a decent example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. EF does some tricks in the context to ensure that you always get the same instance back of a particular entity (basically, it creates an object cache and doesn't create a new instance, unless it can't find an existing instance of that entity in the cache). However, this is *per context*. If you query entity X from context 1 and then query the same entity X from context 2 and attempt to compare them like `x1 == x2`, it will return false.

Your only real option if you need referential integrity is to override `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and the `==` operator on your entity class. However, doing so is not trivial, and it's *very* easy to make a mistake that will either make the equality check overly greedy or overly strict, causing errant `true`/`false` results. It's doable, for sure; just do your research first and make sure you know what you're doing. Microsoft has [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx) to at least get you started.

However, the simpler and more robust solution here is to simply leave the two context scopes disconnected. Do what you need to do in the request scope and then simply ensure that your context in singleton scope always reloads from the database before doing anything. The [documentation on handling concurrency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) should give you a good idea of what you need to do, as this is technically a form of concurrency.

Comment: No? You've probably missed the beginning of the question - *"When receiving an entity from (so it is attached to) DbContext dbContext1, **and then manually attaching this entity to** DbContext dbContext2..."*

Comment: @IvanStoev: that's just replacing one instance with another. As a result, of course they're equal because the instance in context 2 actually is now the same instance in context 1. It's *not* referential equality.

Comment: Also, that only works for one request, because as soon as a new scoped context is created the entity from that will no longer the singleton scoped context, anymore.

Comment: Chris, by "referential equality" they mean "reference identity". Once you attach entity instance to a context, the context is "tracking" it (let say simply holding it into internal list). Then any tracking query against that context will return the same instance. This is what OP was asking. IMHO :)

Comment: @IvanStoev: You are right about what I was asking. My intention was to attach an entity from context A to context B and then receive a referentially equal entity to the one from context A when querying for it within context B. So technically, the answer to the question in the subject is **Yes, that works**. However...

Comment: @ChrisPratt is also right about the fact that it is a bad idea to do what I intended. Because of the fact that the first context is scoped and renewed with every request, I still don't have a solid connection between both "worlds" (with *always* referentially equal entities). So my idea would only ever make sense with both contexts having equal life spans. Otherwise, I shouldn't connect them like this. Got it.